# Armclang with the TMS570

Tags: armv7, ds-5, armclang, tms570

Is it possible to use armclang with the TMS570?

The Cortex-R4F manual states that it supports little endian and byte invariant big endian (BE-8) but NOT word invariant big endian (BE-32), yet the TMS570 says that it is is BE-32.

I am trying to ascertain if it is possible to build TMS570 code using armclang. So far after several days of trying I have not managed to get it to work. I have a feeling this may be due to armclang unable to create BE-32?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out this can be done with the --be32 flag on armlink. This is currently an undocumented feature for the Arm Compiler 6.